# user does not exists in the tenant directory error when calling microsoft graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'am trying to call microsoft graph api, I have did the instructions by microsoft documnets as bellow:

1- app registration in azure portal
Supported account types : all microsoft account users
2- calling 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',tenant_id,'/oauth2/v2.0/authorize' by these parameters:

```
  client_id <-  #Application Id - on the azure app overview page
    client_secret <-# the secret key for my app from azure portal 
    scope <- 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    grant_type <- 'password'
    username <- 'XXX@outlook.com'
    password <-  # the user password
    tenant_id <-# tenant id for my app from azure portal
```

but it has this error:

```
AADSTS50034: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the <tenant_ID> directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory.
```

I have registered my app by the same account that I passed through api.

I want to call my todo list from the graph.

based on @MdFaridUddinKiron's response I added some more explanation:

I think something in my domain in azure is wrong, these are some screenshot of it:
1- it shows "common" for endpoints, what should I use? "common" or my tenant:
[image: endpoits for registered app]
2- my app authentication tab has [image: app authentication tab]some differences, is it important?
3- My domain overview page is look like this:[image: Domain overview]
4- user is added in my active directory[image: user in active directory] 5- user application page:[image: user application page]
6- user assigned role:[image: user assigned role]

I tested  microsoft graph api successfully by the same user in the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I am getting confused how the authentication flow must be.
I just want to call my own todo tasks

Comment: personal `XXX@outlook.com` is not supported for `grant_type:password` user name must  be tenant specific.

Comment: how to set the parameters? can you explain more?

Comment: I have shown you details please have a try and let me know your update.

Comment: Hello is there anything that I can help with?

Comment: Dear @MdFaridUddinKiron I added more information about my problem. Could you please help me more?

Comment: I have updated my answer but don't get your quote `I am getting confused how the authentication flow must be` what did you mean?

Comment: Again, my problem persists. I don't want to use my tenant user, I just want to get my outlook user tasks. I want to know how graph explorer does it without any problem, what is it's authentication parameters?

Comment: its depends on authentication protocol. For individual user you have to follow [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) protocol. But there are some concern on that which you should be aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, please follow the detail steps:

> Make sure email you are trying to get token with is exists in azure ad
>   user list which showed below in details.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:b603c7be_Client_id_e61f925
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret:NpmwO/KDJ_client_secret:NpmwO_W0kWf1SbnL
username:tenentUser.onmicrosoft.com
password:YourUserPassword
grant_type:password
```

See the screen shot:

[image]

I am getting token as expected

***`Step: 1`***

[image]

***`Step: 2`***

[image]

***`Step: 3`***

[image]

***`Step: 4`***

Filter your user from your `azure active directory` user list as shown below.

[image]

***`Note:`***

> 1. Requested token user must be a tenant user for example `YourUser@Yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com`
> 2. User password must be correct that you are suing to token request.
> 3. Make sure your user belong to azure portal on your tenant
> 4. Your Client Id belongs to that tenant
> 5. Application secret is valid or not expired.

**Update:**

> ***What should I use? "common" or my tenant?***
>
> It depends if you have many tenant in that case you can use common.
>   For example user need not to remember specific tenant they would
>   automatically redirected to specific tenant as per the credentials
>   they given.

For more information you could refer [Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

Feel free to share still you are having problem.

Comment: Hi @Md Farid Uddin Kiron, what about if you generate a sharing link to specific people, outside your organization ? I have the same error, really random.